# IPAddress and browser information in ADF application

Tags: oracle-adf

How to retrieve IPAddress and browser information of user in ADF. I am not able to find this in ADFContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ADFContext has a subclass ServletADFContext which should give you access to HTTPRequest which you should be able to get to

request.getHeader("user-agent")

IP Address: request.getRemoteAddr()

Browser: request.getHeader("user-agent")

hope this helps